# word/letter spacing different on smartphone ( android + Firefox )

Tags: android, html, css

**I found the cause, it is text-align: justify; (which i had applied to p). Why does it do this and is there a workaround? – NullBy7e just now edit**

```
p {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    hyphens: auto;
    text-align: justify; 
    text-justify: newspaper;
}
```

--

Here is the page link: http://vizionx.eu/
On desktop this views fine but when you view this on android with Firefox the middle latin text gets random word-spacing, that's what it looks like.

I just want that all the margins, padding, font sizes, spacing etc is the same on mobile as on the desktop, there isn't exactly a page anywhere on the internet that explains how to achieve this.

CSS

```
body {
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:times new roman, times, serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 1em; /* fix for opera */
    word-spacing: 0em;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}

#content { /* contains the latin text */
    font-family: Karla; /* imported with google fonts */
    font-size: 1.2em; /* maybe this is wrong? */
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color: rgb(98,125,77);
}
```

Also just a misc question, if any of you are willing to answer it.

The empty white boxes on the page, the borders of them are invisible on mobile, they become visible when zooming in.....odd.

Comment: My best guess without having an android phone to test with would be to use https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css

Comment: Thanks for that link, I applied the CSS and it is still doing the same.

Comment: I found the cause, it is text-align: justify; (which i had applied to p). Why does it do this and is there a workaround?

Comment: You should edit the question so that it clearly expresses what the problem is. As it is now, the question does not contain the code that actually causes the problem.

Comment: Sorry, the post is edited now. It seems that this is a well known issue with justify, as it adds indents to words differently on some browsers. I found no workaround whatsoever for this.